# What is wrong with my viewport?

Tags: 3d-view, drivers, hardware

I just installed Blender 3.5 and my viewport is completely wrong.
I can't find anything similar to my issue anywhere.
I've installed AMD ProRender plugin.

[image]
.
[image]

Not sure if it's a hardware issue either.

- *GPU Radeon RX550/550 Series
- Discrete VRAM 4096 MB
- GDDR5 1500 MHz Graphics
- Radeon RX550/550 Series GPU
- Radeon RX550/550 Series Discrete
- VRAM 4096 MB GDDR5 1500 MHz
- Driver Version 22.20.27.09-230330a-390451C
- AMD Windows Driver Version 31.0.12044.3
- Direct3D API Version 12.0
- Vulkan™ API Version 1.3.217
- OpenCL™ API Version 2.0
- OpenGL® API Version Not Available
- Direct3D® Driver Version 9.14.10.01523
- Vulkan™ Driver Version 2.0.233
- OpenCL® Driver Version 31.0.12027.9001
- OpenGL® Driver Version 23.03.220823_1f70af4
- Windows Edition Windows 10 Professional (64 bit)
- Windows Version 21H2*

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another layout in the top
press the + button next to scripting
general
layout
check if it works